# kubectl unable to access remote cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

I have a remote cluster with several nodes. I'd like to control it remotely from my laptop. So here is what I did:

1. `scp root@remote-master:/root/.kube/config foo`
2. change it so that the host name (let's say it's `foo` as well) for the master node is used
3. `kubectl --kubeconfig foo get node`

it returns:

```
No resources found.
Error from server (NotAcceptable): unknown (get nodes)
```

I've already checked that the `ca.crt` file is created with domain `foo` and `foo` is resolvable locally on my laptop.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try with `kubectl --kubeconfig foo get node -v=8`, you may found the internal IP of master is called instead of public IP.

Comment: thanks for the tip. It looks like that the server did return valid response but kubectl wasn't able to handle. I think I came across a bug like this

Comment: What do you have with `kubectl version` ? kubectl introduced a backward incompatibility with v1.11 if I recall correctly. Overall I would say you should use a kubectl version matching your cluster version.

Answer (score 1):

Your kubectl version is incompatible with your Kubernetes version.